# Host name and agentId in node name in AppDynamics

Tags: appdynamics

We are in the process of configuring AppDynamics for one of our applications. Since there are many instances of the application, we want to add nodename with agentId and hostName so as to identify the different instances.

Below is how we are trying to do, but it does not seems to work:

```
-Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=CalculationEngine_${agentId}_${network.host}
```

Once I start the JVM the node name appears as CalculationEngine_null_null. I was hoping nodename to come CalculationEngine_3_a301-564.com where 3 being the agentid and a301-564 being the host name.

Also even if the host name parameter is not correct at least it should show CalculationEngine_3_null

What could be wrong here? Or is it not possible?

Comment: What is your OS? and what exactly does not work??

Comment: its on unix, once i start the jvm the node name appears as CalculationEngine_null_null. i was hoping to come atleast CalculationEngine_3_a301-564.com where 3 being the agentid and a301-564 being the host name. Also even if the host name param is not correct atleast it should show CalculationEngine_3_null